# Jsoup parsing from direct link doesn't work

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I need to receive content from website. Generally it works good but I have problem with other one. Webpage has main page where one picture is in the middle and after clicking it, moves us to the another page. I try to show content from direct link but always I receive content from this main page not from page which I want. I use jsoup library. Is there any possibility to solve this? My code:

```
private class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String h;
    String url = "http://www.klt.net.pl/index.php?a=ostatnie_kolejki";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Parser");
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            h = document.html();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        r.setText(h);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried accessing your URL, and by inspecting the network tab I found out that the page you want to access requires a PHPSESSIONID, which is a response cookie from the page with the image. So please try the code below, it should work :)

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .timeout(50000)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.klt.net.pl/index.php")
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .get();
        h = document.html();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Everything works great! This is code which I needed. Many many thanks :) Only thing to correct is link in document for my url.