# Sending data needed to see hidden content from website

Tags: android, authentication, jsoup

Recently I am trying to make app concerns a specific website. I need to have access to page which has visible content after logging. If I understand, below code shows that firstly I need to connect to url1 to avoid default mainpage so here I cannot send data (login, password). I need to see a content from url3, but here I cannot send data also because there is no login and password field. They are in url2. I tried other solutions from this website, but I receive only content that is visible for everyone. Can anybody help?

```
private class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String h;
    String url1 = "http://www.klt.net.pl/";
    String url2 = "http://www.klt.net.pl/index.php?a=logowanie";
    String url3 = "http://www.klt.net.pl/index.php?a=przedmecz1&b=2&d=2038";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Parser");
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url1)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .timeout(50000)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url2)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url1)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .timeout(50000)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .execute();

        Connection.Response loginRes = Jsoup.connect(url2)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")
        .data("login", getlog2,
        "haslo", getpass2)
        .cookies(response.cookies()) 
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = new Map<String, String>();
        cookies.addAll(loginRes.cookies());

        Connection.Response otherRes = Jsoup.connect(url3)
        .cookies(cookies)
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

        d3 = Jsoup.connect(url3)
        .cookies(otherRes.cookies())
        .get();
```

My updated code. Is that ok? I have error in Map (cannot instatiate the type and cannot resolved type).

Comment: Your question is quite unclear

Comment: This can help better to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734928/jsoup-parsing-from-direct-link-doesnt-work/32737661?noredirect=1#comment53330262_32737661 But now I need to get content from url3.

Comment: Hey :) Here to help you out with your second question! So you want to login via url2 to access contents in url3, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login you need to know what **data** to **POST** (id, password, session cookie and etc...), and the **url address** you need to **POST** to.

This information is generally all contained in the login form, I'll explain the steps required to do this below:

**Step 1**: The **ID** and **password** that you need to enter to login should be inputs of a form. So simply right-click the area where you type in your **ID** and select `Inspect Element` (assuming you are on Chrome). There you will be able to inspect the property of the inputs and the form.

**Step 2**: Closely investigate the form and keep record of **ALL INPUT FIELDS** (including hidden fields). You need to know the `name` and `value` of all fields. You also need to know if the form request is made in `GET` or `POST` and the `action` value for the form.

**Step 3**: Now let's get to the fun part. Use the following code snippet to make your request to the server and retrieve the desired content.

```
Connection.Response loginRes = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
                               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
                               .data("login", yourID
                                     "haslo", yourPassword)
                               .cookies(response.cookies()) //this is the same cookie you used for url2!
                               .method(Method.POST)
                               .execute();
```

- `loginUrl` is the request address, which in your case would be `"http://www.klt.net.pl/index.php?a=logowanie"`.
- `userAgent` tells the server your browser details.
- `data` is where you put your name&value pairs of all input fields in the form.
- `cookies` is where you put your cookies, you need to check if your request requires cookies to be accepted by the server, this can be checked in the network tab under "cookies" section. In your case, its the same cookie used for url2.
- `method` specifies your request method.

The retrieved `loginRes` object will contain all the info you need, the html, cookies and everything.

After you've successfully logged in, make sure you store the cookie value in a Map object like below:

```
Map<String, String> cookies;
cookies.putAll(loginRes.cookies());
```

And then make sure to pass this `cookies` to the cookies parameter in all future requests, like below:

```
Connection.Response otherRes = Jsoup.connect(otherUrl).cookies(cookies)....
```

This will ensure that your login session is maintained and the server knows you are authenticated user.

----------------update------------

Declare Map cookie from the beginning of the doInBackground task. Then store **ALL COOKIES** after you make every request. So:

```
cookies = response.cookies();
cookies.putAll(loginRes.cookies();
cookies.putAll(otherRes.cookies();
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but I have a little problem yet. Please check my updated question.

Comment: I've tried it already but it gives me error that i have to initialize variable so i set it to null and then it says to me that the variable can only be null at this location. Problem is harder than i thought :/

Comment: Hey, when first assigning value to cookies, use cookies = loginRes.cookies();

Comment: Then later when you need to update cookies, use cookies.putAll(...);

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Now I receive content from url3 but only this for not logged user. Login and password are ok, because i tested it.

Comment: Please see again my editted post. The page you want to access also requires the cookie you got in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. Now it works! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)