# Filling out a HTML-form with complex name (dot-notation in input-tag) with Java and Jaunt API

Tags: java, html, jsoup, jaunt-api

-
hey folks,

i am building a Java-tool, trying to automatically fill out some form `input` elements in an HTML-Page using Java and `Jaunt API`.

the HTML-Code is like:

```
<fieldset class = "fieldsetlong">
<legend>searchprofile</legend>
<label for="reference">reference:</label>
<input maxlength="50" name="reference" id="reference" type="text" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class = "fieldsetlong">
<legend>searchcriteria</legend>
<label for="surname">surname:</label>
<input name="searchprofile.surname" id="surname" type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

The Java-Code for filling in the "normal" Input-field `reference` (it works) looks like:

```
form.set("reference", "123Test");
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to fill out the fields that use the dot-notation `searchprofile.surname` in the name

Here's a sample of what i've tried (without success):

```
form.set("surname", "TestPerson");
form.set("searchprofile.surname", "TestPerson");
form.set("name=\"searchprofile.surname\"", pers.getSurname());
form.set("id=\"surname\"", pers.getSurname());
```

For each of these commands I get a NotFoundException and don't know whether I can do this with Jaunt.

It would appreciate any kind of help in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Edit - is there a way to  reach the dot-notated input-field `searchprofile.surname` with JSoup?

HTML allows dots in the `name`-Attribute, but does Jaunt accept this `abc.name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, at work the `Jaunt` solution with

```
form.set("searchprofile.surname", "TestPerson");
```

worked like a charm.

I don't know what the problem was earlier but I am glad that it worked.

The `HTML` allows to use dots and minus, etc. which I misinterpreted as some kind of nested forms or hierarchies but the dot-notation is just a valid `name`-attribute in `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `Jaunt`, never used it before. However `Jsoup` seems to be a pretty decent library to be used here. I myself have been using `Jsoup` for a fairly long time and it has been very successful in **scraping web pages**, **filling input form and submit**, and of course, **HTML parsing**!

I've posted a step by step guide to fill in form input fields and submit to server in the following answer: [How to login with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790438/sending-data-needed-to-see-hidden-content-from-website/32792392#32792392)

Basically it works very similar to your code, a very brief example would be:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                    .data("Name", "Value")
                                    .method(Method.POST).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think `JSoup` would be able to reach the `searchprofile.surname` input-field? I will test it tommorow at work.